# Assign Grouped Array into an Array from Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a program which writes an XML file from the data. However the expected output is not as what I intend to get.

Expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAccount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Account>
        <AccountId>A1</AccountId>
        <AccountName>Apple</AccountName>
        <Director>
            <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
            <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
            <UId>U1</UId>
        </Director>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <AccountId>A2</AccountId>
        <AccountName>Microsoft</AccountName>
        <Director>
            <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
            <LastName>Balmer</LastName>
            <UId>U2</UId>
        </Director>
        <Director>
            <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
            <LastName>Gates</LastName>
            <UId>U3</UId>
        </Director>
    </Account>
</ArrayOfAccount>
```

But I am getting the below instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAccount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Account>
        <AccountId>A1</AccountId>
        <AccountName>Apple</AccountName>
        <Directors>
            <Director>
                <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
                <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
                <UId>U1</UId>
            </Director>
        </Directors>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <AccountId>A2</AccountId>
        <AccountName>Microsoft</AccountName>
        <Directors>
            <Director>
                <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
                <LastName>Balmer</LastName>
                <UId>U2</UId>
            </Director>
            <Director>
                <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
                <LastName>Gates</LastName>
                <UId>U3</UId>
            </Director>
        </Directors>
    </Account>
</ArrayOfAccount>
```

from the below code:

```
public class Account
{
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public Director[] Directors { get; set; }
}

public class Director
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UId { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string DirectorFirstName { get; set; }
    public string DirectorLastName { get; set; }
    public string Uid { get; set; }
}


private void Compose()
{
    List<Test.Record> Records = new List<Test.Record>()
    {
        new Test.Record()
        {
            AccountId = "A1",
            AccountName = "Apple",
            DirectorFirstName = "Steve",
            DirectorLastName = "Jobs",
            Uid = "U1"
        },

        new Test.Record()
        {
            AccountId = "A2",
            AccountName = "Microsoft",
            DirectorFirstName = "Steve",
            DirectorLastName = "Balmer",
            Uid = "U2"
        },

        new Test.Record()
        {
            AccountId = "A2",
            AccountName = "Microsoft",
            DirectorFirstName = "Bill",
            DirectorLastName = "Gates",
            Uid = "U3"
        },
    };


    var result = (from r in Records
                  group r by new
                  { r.AccountId, r.AccountName } into g
                  select new Test.Account()
                  {
                      AccountId = g.Key.AccountId,
                      AccountName = g.Key.AccountName,
                      Directors = g.Select(c => new Test.Director()
                      {
                          FirstName = c.DirectorFirstName,
                          LastName = c.DirectorLastName,
                          UId = c.Uid
                      }).ToArray()
                  }
                  ).ToList();


    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(result.GetType());
    x.Serialize(File.Create($"c:\\data\\JKSB_138_COMPOSITE_Test.xml"), result);
}
```

I have written the classes intending to expect the expected output. What do I need to do to get the expected output?

Comment: Add [XmlElement()] before public Director[] Directors { get; set; }